# BIOS / Windows 10 wont read 32gb ram, only 16

Tags: windows-10, memory, motherboard, bios

x99-a 3.1 usb motherboard 
i bought new 2x sticks of ram and i notice they different from the ones i had, i dont know if the problem is in bios or the sticks,
the only diffrence is the first couple model is 
Kingston KHX2133C14D4/8G 8GB and the second one is Kingston KHX2133C14/8G 8GB
they both 2133Mhz and they both cpl14 , all four are the same except that model the difference that letter D4 at the end.
+++
i cannot update my bios x99-a, i read everything in the web and i tried to change file names and i cant update my bios, current version is 1901.
sorry if my English is not good.
thank you for help.

EDIT : 
I added photos, lets make this by order,

1. Heres the photo of my Ram i bought, 2 i own and 2 that are new.
2. Here is how i placement them, by asus manual. (in the grey ones)
3. Heres what it looks in the bios (its still not update here,)
4. it cannot see the new ram installed, after digging and searching the web trying to understand what to do, i found in the FAQ way that says remove the MCOM battery and resotre it back , after that magic happend and only after restart it dissapers

   5. i found out also a way telling me to change the DRAM SVID Support to disable it, and change the voltage to 1.3 but it didnt help. so i put it back

6.ive tried to update the bios and mange to do it but still it aint working as expected to work still not seeing the ram.

7. ive tried to change and mix all the rams and even if i put only the new ram sticks they work and they show 16 gb in the windows, but if i put all four together they dont work.
8. CPU-z shows 32gb ram,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7FEe.jpg HERES THE LINK TO ALL PHOTOS

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJtHB.jpg
but windows see only 16 gb. and bios.

My Pc specs,

Asus x99-a express / i7-5820k 3.3ghz  // gtx 750ti (old :( )

Comment: sometimes when i reset 10-15 times and i watch on bios sometimes it sees the 32GB ram but after restart it loses it, i tried all type of connecting and changing postions, nothing is working.

Comment: what vesion of windows 10 are you running, 32 or 64 bit? also, can you post screenshots of the BIOS, and go into device manager under windows 10 to see if the memory is being picked up by the OS

Comment: i mange to update bios to latest version,
stil when i boot up the bios its sometimes see 32 gb after restart its sees only 16gb.
i will post soon images of everything and explain better.

Comment: Sounds like the ram might not be seated properly, have you tried removing it and putting it back in ? Also provide a photo of the ram in place

Comment: Here i add the photos,
by the way (some photos have the old bios update- after update still wont see the ram)
so here we go,

Comment: ive added photos i edited the post.

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you running? Home, Professional, Ultimate?

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE!

After an insane amount of restarting the pc , its stabilized on 24gb ram, still not 32gb but suddenly at least its sees 3 ram slots, last one still dont show up.

Honestly i did not change nothing just restarted alot and hope and sudden it started to see one more ram, i dont know how to explain this or what can cause it.

Comment: help someone ? :(

Comment: Is this a statement that the problem is solved, or just additional info for the question?  If the latter, this should be merged into the question rather than posting it as an answer.

Comment: Updates are supposed to be edited into the question, not posted as an answer.